# Face landmark detection error (dlib,python,ubuntu)

Tags: python-2.7, image-processing, dlib

I installed Dlib on ubuntu and it's detector works, but when I want to use predictor and using shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat it shows below message:

```
./face_landmark_detection.py shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat ./100032540_1.jpg 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./face_landmark_detection.py", line 66, in <module>
    predictor = dlib.shape_predictor(predictor_path)
RuntimeError: Unexpected version found while deserializing dlib::shape_predictor.
```

how can I fix it?

thanks

Comment: Looks like your version of dlib and the version of the ```shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat``` file are out of sync! You are using a current dlib version and used the [official source](http://dlib.net/files/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat.bz2) for that file?

Comment: I installed it from here: git clone https://github.com/davisking/dlib.git

Comment: my dlib version is: dlib==19.2.99